# android: Programmatically set align on RemoteView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to set `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` or `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` programmatically on my RelativeLayout inside my widget.  I can't seem to access LayoutParams on a RemoteView, so is there another way to do this?  Perhaps a setInt method?

Thanks.